# Convert embedded SVG to PNG image

Tags: svg, png

I have the following embedable SVG code.

```
<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="translate(10,10)"><g><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(215.88235057285917,313.39626554538916)" r="167.2352713250281" style="fill: rgb(247, 46, 28); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(486.71037817537893,313.39626554538916)" r="91.14738895965104" style="fill: rgb(247, 39, 23); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(409.51090217809593,162.87314059547606)" r="65.57275509803134" style="fill: rgb(245, 1, 7); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(300.0434315253036,103.37957293701808)" r="46.57165133723933" style="fill: rgb(248, 58, 36); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(207.11691395084807,99.92169710101888)" r="33.973811934891565" style="fill: rgb(247, 170, 159); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(140.74644065380556,123.914183026187)" r="24.154747282092455" style="fill: rgb(252, 127, 104); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(92.70327222232777,155.26352082123358)" r="20.766487296320776" style="fill: rgb(252, 100, 74); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(55.79662757037886,193.79932826205027)" r="20.146451904888913" style="fill: rgb(246, 25, 16); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(30.481677575703316,239.70262777164234)" r="19.82916511656194" style="fill: rgb(252, 112, 87); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(19.949348813464496,288.6642612778097)" r="17.807115948494484" style="fill: rgb(252, 133, 111); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(20.758026609353465,335.6143361001946)" r="16.704555456364332" style="fill: rgb(243, 183, 176); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(31.473960395205893,379.80401050037017)" r="16.320491348566264" style="fill: rgb(252, 133, 111); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(51.66578134489242,419.6757681954808)" r="15.927168697621724" style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(79.79160982002327,453.90151304134156)" r="15.927168697621724" style="fill: rgb(249, 65, 42); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(114.79635229093068,480.3885603536436)" r="15.523883779079778" style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(196.8239364949025,507.6681946211414)" r="15.523883779079778" style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(154.28109598524838,498.62609847522083)" r="15.523883779079778" style="fill: rgb(252, 135, 113); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(239.89217563699424,506.7013571827707)" r="15.109838928666681" style="fill: rgb(252, 130, 107); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(281.40128007990967,496.8372643128321)" r="15.109838928666681" style="fill: rgb(242, 187, 182); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(319.7671573668492,478.1727112830073)" r="15.109838928666681" style="fill: rgb(239, 195, 192); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(352.57716644925847,451.5707504017654)" r="14.684123988652713" style="fill: rgb(252, 135, 113); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(376.49562353852855,419.546710900952)" r="12.840893924085883" style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(393.6249331350918,386.0488533797601)" r="12.337131823625" style="fill: rgb(250, 156, 139); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(422.21166708857083,409.7272326498353)" r="12.337131823625" style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(455.9643346615917,425.17470605779624)" r="12.337131823625" style="fill: rgb(244, 179, 170); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle><circle class="node node--leaf" transform="translate(491.88731625312886,428.13449962195716)" r="11.262208991190432" style="fill: rgb(241, 189, 184); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"></circle></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(290,290)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"></text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(215.88235057285917,313.39626554538916)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Iraq</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(486.71037817537893,313.39626554538916)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Afghanistan</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(409.51090217809593,162.87314059547606)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Syria</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(300.0434315253036,103.37957293701808)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Libya</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(207.11691395084807,99.92169710101888)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">France</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(140.74644065380556,123.914183026187)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Austria</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(92.70327222232777,155.26352082123358)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Germany</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(55.79662757037886,193.79932826205027)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Ukraine</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(30.481677575703316,239.70262777164234)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Romania</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(19.949348813464496,288.6642612778097)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Belarus</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(20.758026609353465,335.6143361001946)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Serbia</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(31.473960395205893,379.80401050037017)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Peru</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(51.66578134489242,419.6757681954808)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Italy</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(79.79160982002327,453.90151304134156)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Netherlands</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(114.79635229093068,480.3885603536436)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Colombia</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(196.8239364949025,507.6681946211414)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Canada</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(154.28109598524838,498.62609847522083)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Ecuador</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(239.89217563699424,506.7013571827707)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Turkey</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(281.40128007990967,496.8372643128321)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Belgium</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(319.7671573668492,478.1727112830073)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Switzerland</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(352.57716644925847,451.5707504017654)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Czech Republic</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(376.49562353852855,419.546710900952)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Slovenia</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(393.6249331350918,386.0488533797601)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">United States</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(422.21166708857083,409.7272326498353)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Malta</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(455.9643346615917,425.17470605779624)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Russia</text><text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(491.88731625312886,428.13449962195716)" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Brazil</text></g></g></svg>
```

How do convert this into a PNG image?

I have Photoshop but I cannot open it in that, so I need some other free tools or resources that can do this for me.

Comment: Why can't you open it in Photoshop?

Comment: @Cai depends on version of PS. not all PS versions open svg. Though illustrator does in this case. As does your browser, so why not use chorme or firefox for this?

Comment: @joojaa How do I use chrome for taking the code in my question and turning it into a PNG image? Could explain the exact steps as an answer because this may help for similar problems in the future.

Comment: Press print screen, paste it to a app that edits images. But yes you can also ask chrome to save it as png with javascript.

Comment: Is there something sensitive about having the svg in the post?

Comment: Yes its part of a larger project and would like the image removed please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the code into [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/index.html#download).

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do this again for a similar image, I have dropped the code into Blue Griffon, and it is showing the SVG image, but how do I export it as a PNG?

Comment: screen capture !

Answer (score 5):

You can open SVGs in Inkscape - it's free and open source. It can also export PNGs.

[Here's your SVG code](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/test_407) inserted into a plain SVG document which will open in Inkscape.

Edit: oops that link is dead! Anyhoo, here's the SVG code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg114"
   version="1.1"
   height="600"
   width="600">
  <metadata
     id="metadata120">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs118" />
  <g
     id="g112"
     transform="translate(10,10)">
    <g
       id="g54">
      <circle
         id="circle2"
         style="fill: rgb(247, 46, 28); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="167.2352713250281"
         transform="translate(215.88235057285917,313.39626554538916)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle4"
         style="fill: rgb(247, 39, 23); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="91.14738895965104"
         transform="translate(486.71037817537893,313.39626554538916)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle6"
         style="fill: rgb(245, 1, 7); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="65.57275509803134"
         transform="translate(409.51090217809593,162.87314059547606)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle8"
         style="fill: rgb(248, 58, 36); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="46.57165133723933"
         transform="translate(300.0434315253036,103.37957293701808)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle10"
         style="fill: rgb(247, 170, 159); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="33.973811934891565"
         transform="translate(207.11691395084807,99.92169710101888)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle12"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 127, 104); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="24.154747282092455"
         transform="translate(140.74644065380556,123.914183026187)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle14"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 100, 74); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="20.766487296320776"
         transform="translate(92.70327222232777,155.26352082123358)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle16"
         style="fill: rgb(246, 25, 16); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="20.146451904888913"
         transform="translate(55.79662757037886,193.79932826205027)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle18"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 112, 87); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="19.82916511656194"
         transform="translate(30.481677575703316,239.70262777164234)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle20"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 133, 111); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="17.807115948494484"
         transform="translate(19.949348813464496,288.6642612778097)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle22"
         style="fill: rgb(243, 183, 176); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="16.704555456364332"
         transform="translate(20.758026609353465,335.6143361001946)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle24"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 133, 111); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="16.320491348566264"
         transform="translate(31.473960395205893,379.80401050037017)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle26"
         style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.927168697621724"
         transform="translate(51.66578134489242,419.6757681954808)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle28"
         style="fill: rgb(249, 65, 42); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.927168697621724"
         transform="translate(79.79160982002327,453.90151304134156)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle30"
         style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.523883779079778"
         transform="translate(114.79635229093068,480.3885603536436)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle32"
         style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.523883779079778"
         transform="translate(196.8239364949025,507.6681946211414)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle34"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 135, 113); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.523883779079778"
         transform="translate(154.28109598524838,498.62609847522083)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle36"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 130, 107); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.109838928666681"
         transform="translate(239.89217563699424,506.7013571827707)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle38"
         style="fill: rgb(242, 187, 182); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.109838928666681"
         transform="translate(281.40128007990967,496.8372643128321)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle40"
         style="fill: rgb(239, 195, 192); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="15.109838928666681"
         transform="translate(319.7671573668492,478.1727112830073)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle42"
         style="fill: rgb(252, 135, 113); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="14.684123988652713"
         transform="translate(352.57716644925847,451.5707504017654)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle44"
         style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="12.840893924085883"
         transform="translate(376.49562353852855,419.546710900952)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle46"
         style="fill: rgb(250, 156, 139); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="12.337131823625"
         transform="translate(393.6249331350918,386.0488533797601)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle48"
         style="fill: rgb(235, 203, 204); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="12.337131823625"
         transform="translate(422.21166708857083,409.7272326498353)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle50"
         style="fill: rgb(244, 179, 170); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="12.337131823625"
         transform="translate(455.9643346615917,425.17470605779624)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
      <circle
         id="circle52"
         style="fill: rgb(241, 189, 184); fill-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-opacity: 0;"
         r="11.262208991190432"
         transform="translate(491.88731625312886,428.13449962195716)"
         class="node node--leaf" />
    </g>
    <g
       id="g110">
      <text
         id="text56"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(290,290)"
         text-anchor="middle" />
      <text
         id="text58"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(215.88235057285917,313.39626554538916)"
         text-anchor="middle">Iraq</text>
      <text
         id="text60"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(486.71037817537893,313.39626554538916)"
         text-anchor="middle">Afghanistan</text>
      <text
         id="text62"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(409.51090217809593,162.87314059547606)"
         text-anchor="middle">Syria</text>
      <text
         id="text64"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(300.0434315253036,103.37957293701808)"
         text-anchor="middle">Libya</text>
      <text
         id="text66"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(207.11691395084807,99.92169710101888)"
         text-anchor="middle">France</text>
      <text
         id="text68"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(140.74644065380556,123.914183026187)"
         text-anchor="middle">Austria</text>
      <text
         id="text70"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(92.70327222232777,155.26352082123358)"
         text-anchor="middle">Germany</text>
      <text
         id="text72"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(55.79662757037886,193.79932826205027)"
         text-anchor="middle">Ukraine</text>
      <text
         id="text74"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(30.481677575703316,239.70262777164234)"
         text-anchor="middle">Romania</text>
      <text
         id="text76"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(19.949348813464496,288.6642612778097)"
         text-anchor="middle">Belarus</text>
      <text
         id="text78"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(20.758026609353465,335.6143361001946)"
         text-anchor="middle">Serbia</text>
      <text
         id="text80"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(31.473960395205893,379.80401050037017)"
         text-anchor="middle">Peru</text>
      <text
         id="text82"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(51.66578134489242,419.6757681954808)"
         text-anchor="middle">Italy</text>
      <text
         id="text84"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(79.79160982002327,453.90151304134156)"
         text-anchor="middle">Netherlands</text>
      <text
         id="text86"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(114.79635229093068,480.3885603536436)"
         text-anchor="middle">Colombia</text>
      <text
         id="text88"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(196.8239364949025,507.6681946211414)"
         text-anchor="middle">Canada</text>
      <text
         id="text90"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(154.28109598524838,498.62609847522083)"
         text-anchor="middle">Ecuador</text>
      <text
         id="text92"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(239.89217563699424,506.7013571827707)"
         text-anchor="middle">Turkey</text>
      <text
         id="text94"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(281.40128007990967,496.8372643128321)"
         text-anchor="middle">Belgium</text>
      <text
         id="text96"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(319.7671573668492,478.1727112830073)"
         text-anchor="middle">Switzerland</text>
      <text
         id="text98"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(352.57716644925847,451.5707504017654)"
         text-anchor="middle">Czech Republic</text>
      <text
         id="text100"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(376.49562353852855,419.546710900952)"
         text-anchor="middle">Slovenia</text>
      <text
         id="text102"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(393.6249331350918,386.0488533797601)"
         text-anchor="middle">United States</text>
      <text
         id="text104"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(422.21166708857083,409.7272326498353)"
         text-anchor="middle">Malta</text>
      <text
         id="text106"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(455.9643346615917,425.17470605779624)"
         text-anchor="middle">Russia</text>
      <text
         id="text108"
         style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"
         transform="translate(491.88731625312886,428.13449962195716)"
         text-anchor="middle">Brazil</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

an easier way would be to copy the code into a text editor save as .svg then open in Inkscape or whatever and save as png